# SHChangeNotifyRegister API - How to know if 'file creation' is caused by file copy or not?

Tags: winapi

the Windows API `SHChangeNotifyRegister` can detect file creation in disk, but how to know if 'file creation' is caused by file copy or not? thank you!

[EDITED], I mean `SHChangeNotifyRegister`, but not `SHChangeNotify`, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file name which is changed you can examine it's [creation and last write times](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290%28VS.85%29.aspx) with respect of [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320%28VS.85%29.aspx). If you copy a file from one directory to another you don't modify the file contain, so the last write times will stay unchanged.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, but I seem can't get the source file name in the notification events fired by API SHChangeNotifyRegister...

Comment: @Edwin: You can download "Common Notify Watcher Sample" example from the http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/shellapplication. It shows how to see the path of the modilied file. In case of copy of the new file in the watching directory you will receive the `SHCNE_CREATE` message with the name of the new file. You need to have only the **destination** file name (the name on new file). You get its create time and the last write time. It file was copied, the create time will be **newer** (the time of file coping) as the last write time which stay unchanged.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you so much, even I've not tried it but I think it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

SHChangeNotify is not an API which tells you that something has changed, but an API which **you** tell the shell **that you changed** something and it should update its views accordingly.

Maybe what you want is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Stefan, sorry for the confusion! I meant to write SHChangeNotifyRegister :P